# Why the table can get $row['staffName'] but the value='.$row['staffName'].' cannot get full value?

Tags: php

Why the table can get $row['staffName'] but the value='.$row['staffName'].' cannot get full value?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td >" . $row['staffName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['staffPhone'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['staffEmail'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['staffName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['staffName'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>" ;
  $staffId = $row['staffId'];

  echo "<a class ='editbutton' href='#$staffId'>Edit</a>";
  echo '<div id='.$staffId.'  class="overlayEdit" >';
  echo '<div class="popupEdit">';
  echo '<a class="closeEdit" href="#">&times;</a>';
  echo '<form name="formEdit" method="post" action="newStaff_connect.php">';
  echo '<h3>Update Staff</h3>';
  echo '<HR color="#D8D8D8" size="2" width="100%"></HR><br>';
  echo '<h5>Full Name</h5>';
  echo '<input type="text" name="staffName" value='.$row['staffName'].'><br>';
  echo '<h5>Contact</h5>';
  echo '<input type="text" name="staffPhone" value='.$row['staffPhone'].'><br>';
  echo '<h5>Email Address</h5>';
  echo '<input type="email" name="staffEmail" value='.$row['staffEmail'] .'><br>';
  echo '<input type="button" class="btn-login" value="Update" onClick="newStaffCheck()" />';
  echo '</form>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  echo "</td>" ;
  echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>" ;
  echo "<a class ='editbutton' href='?delete_id=".$row['staffId']."'>Delete</a>"; 
  echo "</td>" ;
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

[the table can get "Chan Tai Man"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLhCC.png)

[but input just show the "Chan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjKsT.png)

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the ":

```
echo '<input type="text" name="staffName" value="'.$row['staffName'].'"><br>';
```

Also here:

```
echo '<div id='.$staffId.'  class="overlayEdit" >';
```

Should be:

```
echo '<div id="'.$staffId.'"  class="overlayEdit" >';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are so smart ! i can get full value now !

Answer (score 0):

What you have:

```
 echo '<input type="text" name="staffName" value='.$row['staffName'].'><br>';
```

What it should be:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="staffName" value="'.$row['staffName'].'"><br>';
```

notice the double quotes to wrap the value= contents. 
notice the single quotes to end the line. 
The part `.$row['staffName'].` will concatinate and substitute that part of the line with the value of the variable $row['staffName']. 
And then again the last part is within single quotes again, with a double quote being the closing quote for the value-attribute's contents.

More lines are affected by this error.